# xsd element name not resolved in unit test

Tags: java, xsd

I am trying to validate xml files in a junit unit test. This is my simplified code. Schemas are accessible from http://www.unece.org/ and http://www.gs1.org/

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Epcis11MessageCreatorForSoTest {

    private static Schema schema;

    private final static String[] XSD_FILES = { 
            "epcis11/xsd/BasicTypes.xsd", 
            "epcis11/xsd/DocumentIdentification.xsd",
            "epcis11/xsd/Partner.xsd",
            "epcis11/xsd/Manifest.xsd", 
            "epcis11/xsd/BusinessScope.xsd",
            "epcis11/xsd/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd", 
            "epcis11/xsd/EPCglobal.xsd",
            "epcis11/xsd/EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd",
            "epcis11/xsd/EPCglobal-epcis-query-1_1.xsd",
            "epcis11/xsd/EPCglobal-epcis-masterdata-1_1.xsd",
    };

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.setProperty("jaxp.debug", "10");

            SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            Source[] sources = new Source[XSD_FILES.length];
            int i = 0;
            for (String xsdfile : XSD_FILES) {
                URL resource = Epcis11MessageCreatorForSoTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(xsdfile); 
                String systemId = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
                StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(
                        Epcis11MessageCreatorForSoTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xsdfile),systemId);

                sources[i] = ss;
                i++;
            }
            schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(sources);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
    @Test   
    public void testFoo() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

However the schema is not being built due to:

> target/test-classes/epcis11/xsd/EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd; lineNumber: 46; columnNumber: 60; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'sbdh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.

Relevant lines look like this (EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd)

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" xmlns:sbdh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" xmlns:epcglobal="urn:epcglobal:xsd:1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1">
...
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" schemaLocation="./StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd"/>
...
<xsd:element ref="sbdh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"/>
```

I use Eclipse as an ide and project uses JavaSE-1.7 as JRE System Library. When looking at these xsd-files they are syntactically ok. That is I do not get any xml-related errors in ide. Exactly same error appears when test is either run from within ide or through maven.

Any suggestions about what might be wrong with my schemafactory or xsd sources as java objects?

Comment: where is the namespace `sbdh` defined?

Comment: The namespace prefix 'sbdh' is in EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd. There is a snippet of the line above.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I have the exact same issue in my java project.

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky to have some time to run my code through a debugger. It was pretty heavy stuff. For example com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.class contains over 100 imports and over 4000 lines of code.

Anyhow, I am willing to think that there is a programming error in com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLInputSource) that loads xsd grammars, or schemas or schemasources in our context.

First grammar loaded for http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader namespace is BasicTypes.xsd.

My findings are that, that grammar is mapped by its namespace and after it is included by other schemas it somehow is prevententing the includers', that share the namespace, grammars from being mapped. I can succesfully refer from EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd to any type defined in BasicTypes.xsd, but referring to any other element or type in http:/ /www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader namespace that is *not* defined in BasicTypes.xsd results in a name resolving error.

My theory is backed up by that, if I move any type definition or element declaration to BasicTypes.xsd I can succesfully refer from EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd to that type or element .

As a matter of fact I can, unwillingly, consolidate all type definitions and element declarations in namespace http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader that are used in this project into one xsd source file and then the schema is built correctly.

But since none of the xsd-files used for validation is maintained by me this feels like some sort of hack. I would rather use a system that can build an xml schema from my project files as they are.

Comment: Related to this issue is now a bug approved by Oracle: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8168883

Comment: Did you ever find the fix? I am still facing the same issue even after 7 years. Can you please suggest something?